# Issue running uWebsockets examples using vcpkg and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, manifest, vcpkg

I want to build [`EchoServer.cpp`](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/examples/EchoServer.cpp) example of [`uWebsockets`](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) C++ library using vcpkg manifest mode.

```
my-app
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   vcpkg.json
│
└───examples
        CMakeLists.txt
        EchoServer.cpp
```

**Contents of `vcpkg.json`**:

```
{
  "name": "myfirst",
  "version-string": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "uwebsockets"
  ]
}
```

**Contents of `CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(my-app VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

find_path(UWEBSOCKETS_INCLUDE_DIRS "uwebsockets/App.h")

add_subdirectory(examples)
```

**Contents of `examples\CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(projExamples VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(EchoServerExample EchoServer.cpp)
target_include_directories(EchoServerExample PRIVATE ${UWEBSOCKETS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The toolchain is properly passed to my CLion IDE by `"DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Dev\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"`. When I configure my project, vcpkg works correctly and installs `uWebsockets` and prints the following message:

```
...
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * libuv[core]:x64-windows -> 1.46.0
  * usockets[core]:x64-windows -> 0.8.6#1
    uwebsockets[core]:x64-windows -> 20.45.0
  * vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows -> 2023-05-04
  * vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows -> 2022-02-06#1
  * zlib[core]:x64-windows -> 1.2.13
...
find_path(UWEBSOCKETS_INCLUDE_DIRS "uwebsockets/App.h")
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${UWEBSOCKETS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I don't know how I should utilize `uWebsockets` in the `CMakeLists.txt`  in example subdirectory. Because of this, I am getting the following error when I run `EchoServerExample.exe`. It appears to me that it is not able to find the dependencies of `uWebsockets`: `zlib`, `uv`, `uSockets`.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'uv.lib'
```

Is this the correct way of integrating `uWebsockets` into my project directory using `vcpkg.json`? Could someone kindly help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably better off using `find_package` then linking to the resulting target, that should configure everything for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration#using-libraries

Comment: It can find zlib with `find_package(zlib REQUIRED)` but `find_package(uv REQUIRED)` fails.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of that, just find `uWebsockets` and link to it and it should automatically bring in the dependencies

Comment: it's not working for me. `find_package(uWebsockets REQUIRED)` gives me `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "uWebsockets" with
  any of the following names:

    uWebsocketsConfig.cmake
    uwebsockets-config.cmake`

Comment: Are you passing the vcpkg toolchain to cmake?

Comment: Yes. vcpkg is working and installs everything. It's the `CMakeLists.txt` that is not right. The MWE is simple to create and you can reproduce the error if you want.